# Graphhopper not working in release apk.

Tags: java, android, android-proguard, android-studio-2.2, graphhopper

I have developed an android application using the graphhopper routing library. The library works fine in debug mode or in app-debug.apk but when I create a release apk of the app the library wont work. It is giving me **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input stream found in class path!?** exception upon execution of the following code.

```
/*
*Constants.ROUTE_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/.myappfolder/routes";
*/
 File routingFiles = new File(Constants.ROUTE_FILE_PATH);
 GraphHopper tmpHopp = new GraphHopper().forMobile();
 tmpHopp.load(routingFiles.getAbsolutePath());
```

While creating the release apk i got some warning for the graphhopper library and removed the warnings using

```
-dontwarn com.graphhopper.**
```

in the proguard-rules.pro file.

Is there any issue with creating a release apk of the graphhopper project?
Why wont the library work in release version of the apk?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found 2 answers to the issue.

Firstly, you can set

```
minifyEnabled false
```

in **build.gradle**. This works as a solution too but your app wont get minified.

Secondly according [to the answer posted here](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/graphhopper-not-working-in-release-apk/1252/2?u=yogesh10446) you can set

```
-keep class com.graphhopper.** { *; }
```

in the **proguard-rules.pro**.

So whichever answer suits you best.